# Merge multiple branches into master with all the files

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I'm using Git to version control my thesis although I'm quite a Git noob.

I put each chapter in a separate branch which is recommended on the web. But now as I mostly finished all of them, I just wanted to merge them into master, or only to gather them together so that I can use pandoc to merge those separate files into one.

I thought it could work simply by doing

```
git merge branch1 branch2 ...
```

But it failed which I guess was due to some commits, it says

```
Should not be doing an Octopus.
Merge with strategy octopus failed.
```

Then I tried what was suggested online

```
git merge branch1 branch2 ... --strategy=ours
```

It turned out that It did put all of the commits from all branches together, but no files showed up.

So what should be the right way to do this in my situation? Thanks!

FYI: all my files in different branches have unique names.

Update: I think the reason that the merge fails is this: there was separte README file in each branch which I later deleted but kept one in master. So even if I merge all the branches separately I still have to fix the conflicts every time.

```
$ git merge abstract
CONFLICT (modify/delete): README.md deleted in abstract and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of README.md left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

My goal is simply to have all my files for the chapter in one place.

Comment: You snipped the error message from the failed merge that explains what the problem is

Comment: I updated my post and here's the full message.

 Trying simple merge with abstract
 Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
 ERROR: README.md: Not handling case 0dbb51c49ce3d733a2345b32a0e59466db7226a2 -> 5dc8372ffeb6e86529bd3b8d5abc523af491fcd1 -> 
 fatal: merge program failed
 Automated merge did not work.
 Should not be doing an Octopus.
 Merge with strategy octopus failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see it, the message "Should not be doing an Octopus" indicates that there are conflicts which cannot be resolved automatically. Octopus merges are intended for simple merges only that resolve without any conflict.

In your case, I'd suggest to perform one merge per branch.